# How to find minimum number of k-input LUT's needed to express a n variable boolean function?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, boolean

An k-input LUT (look up table) takes in atmost k-inputs and gives 1 output (which is a function of the k inputs). I need to devise an algorithm to find the minimum number of k-input LUT's required to express a n variable boolean function.

For example : - n=8 and k=4 8 input variables are a0,a1...a7

1) f1(a0,a1,..a7)= a0*a1 +a3*a4 + a5*a7 + a6*a8 Requires 3 LUTs : LUT1 :a0*a1 + a3*a4 =x1 LUT2 :a5*a7 + a6*a8 =x2 LUT3 : x1+x2

2) f2(a0,a1,..a7)= a0*a1 +a3*a4 + a5*a7 + a6 Requires 2 LUTs : LUT1: a0*a1 +a3*a4 =x1 LUT2: x1+a5*a7+a6

Comment: @PravithaV Your edit is not very helpful. Using quote formatting for something that isn't a quote and code formatting for something that isn't code does not enhance the readability of the post. Please don't teach our new users bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

The first LUT can handle k inputs. If you have more than k inputs you will need more LUTs which have to be combined. In that case all LUTs but the very last one produce an output that is an input as well, so these LUTs effectively add just k-1 inputs to the system. So (n-1)/(k-1) is the number of minimal LUTs. Of course you have to round up.